# how to define if one of kubernetes pods is not ready, using jsonpath and shell scripts?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, jsonpath

I have a script with command that is sleeping if pods with specific labels is not ready. But it does not work if there are a few pods (in this way it need to be like condition != "true true true"). How can I check, if one of any pods is not ready (ready = false)?

```
while [ "$(kubectl get pods -l=app.kubernetes.io/instance=loki -n grafana -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[0].ready}')" != "true" ]; do
   sleep 5
   echo "Waiting for Loki to be ready."
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check to see if any pods have `.ready` equal to `false` like this:

```
while kubectl get pods \
    -l=app.kubernetes.io/instance=loki \
    -n grafana \
    -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[0].ready}' | grep -q false; do
   echo "Waiting for Loki to be ready."
   sleep 5
done
```